# Alternative to implement scroll from jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I am trying to implement a drag-scrolling function of div elements by using jQuery/JavaScript to set CSS3 properties. I came up with the possibility of manipulating the following css style parameters, and am wondering which one to go with. What is the difference between setting the properties as below?

- `obj.style.transform = 'translate(x, y)';`
- `obj.style.top = x; obj.style.left = y;`
- `obj.scrollTop = x; obj.scrollLeft = y;`

I don't care at all about legacy web browsers. Please assume that I am using only the latest browsers. Compatibility is not an issue.

Comment: Do you have some example (a website, Plunk, JSFiddle, etc.) of what you're trying to accomplish? I'm not really sure what this behavior would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
obj.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(x, y, 0)'
```

Thus, you will use GPU acceleration and your scrolling will be smooth enough.
Transform prop is available with special vendor prefix for all modern browsers.
To change this prop use requestAnimationFrame or css3 animations to achieve best fps.